# Github Pages subdomain on own website

Tags: subdomain, github

I currently have set up Github Pages so that my main domain (eg. www.example.com) shows my username.github.io page, by adding a CNAME file with the content: "www.example.com".

Now, for another project that has nothing to do with Github, I want to create a new subdomain: foo.example.com

I cannot figure out how to set this up correctly. I've created the subdomain in my DirectAdmin panel but I keep getting "Server not found" errors.

Is this possible at all?

Best,

Comment: How long since you added the subdomain record? DNS takes some time to propagate, up to 2 days sometimes.

Comment: Can you add more detail regarding your DNS settings?? For example, are you setting this with your registrar or host? What records are you setting and some detail?? This should be easy to resolve. Sub-domains should be immediate if they are set with the DNS that is the SOA for the parent domain. Otherwise, there is not enough detail to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

In this sort of an instance it is generally to do with the DNS records not being fully propagated yet which is generally to do with how long your DNS host takes to propagate changes and has nothing to do with using Github pages.

When this happens you can wait 2 days and try again, and if it still hasn't worked then you will need to speak to your DNS host to get them to take a look.